# How to display images in gridview when in database table we have stored image name only. How to give imgae path if it is inside a folder Eg. images

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

In a  C# program, I'm required to insert an image tag in one of the gridview's column Eg.selected_image(column_name).

the images are stored in a folder named **product_imgs**.

in the database, I have stored only the image names not the complete path eg product_imgs/

### tbimg

### imgcod    imgnam

1          abc.jpg
2          pqr.jpg etc..

I'm having trouble displaying these images in the grid view. As the control inside gridview must have runat = server tag in order to work (i might be wrong here*)

what I have done is:**(Sample Code)**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Width="1195px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double"
    BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal" Style="margin-left: 45px; margin-right: 44px;"
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Secondary Balloon(if any)">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img id="sb" height="150" width="150" alt="SellerChoice Or Multicolor"
                    src='~/Product_Imgs/<%#Eval("addimg")%>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks In Advance And have an amazing day.

Comment: There are two schools of thought on how to store BLOBs (inlcuding Images) with a Database, with a few attempts to combine the 2 (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/). Your approach requires that the files are in a folder exposed as part of normal webserver operation. The same way images have been exposed on Webservers since the earliest days of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the url of the image will be incorrect. Do this

```
<img src="/Product_Imgs/<%# Eval("addimg") %>" />
```

Or this

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "/Product_Imgs/" + Eval("addimg")  %>' />
```